# How would this series going to infinity behave?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I just was going through some homework and in the process of doing a question I wanted some clarity regarding how a series will behave when going to infinity.

As an example, when I see the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n}+3^{n}}{3^{n}+4^{n}}$ we have been shown in class that the fraction would "behave like" $\frac{3^n}{4^n}$. With that, I would think to use a comparison test in this scenario.

What I would like to ask about is a slightly different series such as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^{n}+7^{n}}{8^{n}-5^{n}}$. Would this also "behave like" $\frac{7^n}{8^n}$? Although its a small change, the subtraction in the denominator has made me a little unsure and wanted to know how to approach this series to determine its convergence/divergence.

Comment: The idea is to consider the "dominant terms." My computer science students find this useful. If $1 < a < b$, how does $a^n$ compare to $b^n?$

Comment: You need to say more about what you were actually shown in class and what exactly was meant by "behaves like".

Comment: @RobArthan My apologies, the above comment from Sean put it in a better way by describing which terms are dominant in the question.

Comment: @SeanRoberson If I am understanding it correct, $b^{n}\gt a^{n}$. Does this mean that even though my example has the denominator $8^{n}-5^{n}$, the $8^{n}$ would get bigger so much faster that I can "ignore" the $-5^{n}$?

Comment: Using the term "dominates" doesn't help much either. in $\frac{2^n+3^n}{3^n+4^n}$ $4^n$ dominates $3^n$ and $3^n$ dominates $2^n$, but that doesn't immediately let us apply the comparison theorem because $3^n$ appears both in the numerator and the denominator. You need a more subtle argument: see the answer that has now been provided.

Comment: Be careful, an inequality is not enough. $8^n +1> 8^n$ for all $n$, but you shouldn't ignore  $8^n$ when compared with $8^n+1$. What is important is not that $8^n > 5^n$ but the fact that $5^n/8^n \to 0$ when $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find addition and subtraction in fractions too hard to deal with. Multiplication and division play much nicer with fractions.

Your intuition is that the denominator $8^n - 5^n$ “behaves like” $8^n$ as $n$ goes to infinity. While $8^n - 5^n$ is certainly smaller than $8^n$, we do have this inequality:
$$
8^n - 5^n > \frac{1}{4}\cdot 8^n,
$$
for all $n \geq 1$. Thus,
$$
\frac{3^n + 7^n}{8^n - 5^n} < \frac{3^n + 7^n}{\frac{1}{4}\cdot 8^n} = 4\cdot\frac{3^n + 7^n}{8^n},
$$
which hopefully looks easier to run a comparison test with.

PS I found the factor of $\frac{1}{4}$ just by guess and check. Typically with these exponentials you just have to check $n=1$ and the rest works out, though it never hurts to check a few more cases. This sort of thing works whenever you have one term that dominates another.

Comment: This cleared up the remaining questions I had. As you could see I also find addition/subtraction a bit of a pain in fractions. I don't know why I didn't think to just use multiplication but seeing how you framed it, it is super obvious. Seeing how you presented the result I could now easily use the comparison test on it. 

Thank you.